# django modeladmin list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to play with the Django's official tutorial. Specifically the modeladmin list_display:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-change-list

How can I add a column that displays the number of choices for each poll in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define/save the choices for your polls?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to edit your model, to calculate columns for admin on the fly create a function in the ModelAdmin object that takes a second param, this will be the regular Poll model instance.  Than write code just like you would in a model, you can ignore the self here since it doesn't have what you want.

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    list_display = (<other_fields>, 'choice_count')

    def choice_count(self, model_instance):
        return model_instance.choice_set.count()
```

Comment: HA! i was having trouble because of capitalization. Strange.

Comment: Both of these should work. If you don't use choice count anywhere else but the admin they you can define this on `ModelAdmin`, if you need the choice count available in several places you will want to use the model approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom method (say `pcount`) that returns the number of choices for a given `Poll` instance. You can then add this to the `list_display` attribute in your `ModelAdmin` subclass.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    ...
    def pcount(self):
        return self.choice_set.count()


class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (<other fields>, 'pcount', )
```

Comment: This returns (none), even though there are 5 choices in each. :(

Comment: I added the missing `return` statement to the `pcount` method. Did you miss that?

Comment: @M.A.: quite strange. Can you see what `pcount` returns for any instance of `Poll` from the Django shell?